# Exceptation Maximization and priors

Tags: algorithms, normal-distribution

Estimating the parameters of gaussians to fit a lot of samples can be do with Exceptation Maximization, for instance if we want to fit two gaussian on points, to have the clusters $a$ and $b$. ([1](https://youtu.be/iQoXFmbXRJA))

$$
b_i = P(b|x_i) = \frac{P(x_i|b) P(b)}{P(x_i|b) P(b)+P(x_i|b) P(a)}
$$

Here $P(b)$ is the prior that depicts the overall importance of the $b$ cluster.

This prior is then updated for the next step, according on how many the points belongs to the $b$ cluster:

$$
P(b) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i b_i
$$

However, what is the value of the prior $P(b)$ on the first iteration of the algorithm?

Comment: It would be nice if you could write out your notation and definitions ([preferably in latex/mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)), rather than ask people to watch a video to figure it out (which some [many] may not be inclined to do).

Comment: I've edited the post, hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197865/initializing-em-algorithm/197867) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/how-to-initialize-em-algorithm-when-trying-to-fit-data-to-a-separable-mixture-mo).

Some simple suggestions: you could initialize with $k$-means and/or run multiple tries with different random initialization. Note that it is possible for EM algorithms to get stuck in local minima, so multiple initializations can be useful.

Hopefully that's useful!